# Google Sheets: IMPORTRANGE Values Matched To A Custom ID

Tags: google-sheets

I am building a Google sheet that references data from a source sheet where columns and rows may shift, and values may even change. Because shifting can occur, an ID system has been implemented. Here is a very simplified version:

[image: Example Source Sheet]

In my own sheet, the goal is to pull in values and place them based on the corresponding ID.  Currently, to pull this off, I am using the IMPORTRANGE function with a FILTER to get the desired value, based on the ID in the column. So to find and place the value "United States" underneath ID 1, I use the following:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("doc_url", "Sheet1!A1:A5"),IMPORTRANGE("doc_url", "Sheet1!B1:B5")=A1)
```

[image: Example My Own Sheet]

I am aware it's not super great to use IMPORTRANGE on a cell-by-cell basis, as it becomes quite intensive with heavy usage (and the actual sheet I am building has many more values to pull). I feel like there must be a more efficient way to pull and arrange these values by the correct ID, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far.

Is it possible to build a function that would pull the full range in the order I am expecting all in one go?

- [Example Source Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cvzQAh2Kq1SLYsH1jt6X3hQQioBrbFT4smw86T_wdUw)
- [Example Target Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DvO9lhXc4FVfMjCzDrl1YoncCd3zOU9JlANqTThHavY)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 updated with links to the example sheets. Based on your suggestion, I think you've understood the premise, but the desired output for the target sheet is to look exactly as it does in the above image, but I would import the range using just one instance of the IMPORTRANGE function, instead of calling the function in each cell where I want a value. I posted some errors I received after trying your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try in A2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(HLOOKUP(A1:E1, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("doc_url", "Sheet1!A1:B5"), 
 "select Col2,Col1", )), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Implementing this with the proper url, I received a Query error (`Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2`). This is confusing to me since Col2 definitely seems to exist. Removing Col2 entirely results in an HLOOKUP error (`HLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range`), referring to A1:E1, though for all know, fixing the Col2 issue may resolve this as well. Any thoughts on these? I've updated the original post with links to the actual example sheets, if that's helpful.

Comment: @enels fixed. try now